# Is there a HTML5 way of pre-filling an email form field with a value previously entered in another email form field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a series of forms one following the other, each with a different URL.

At one point there's an email address form field, then later on in a different form, there's a second email address form field: as per my app, the second one should usually get the same value as the first one, so I want to pre-fill the second one with first one's value.

Is there some simple native HTML5 way to achieve this, or do I need to do it programmatically?

Comment: You have to do this using jquery or js with onkeyup event.

Comment: it depends on how you do the deploy in production. If you just have static html, no client scripting and no server side delivery, the only option I see is to hard code the addresses. If you on the other hand use client scripting, you have many options, like hidden fields, context variables, global variables, occupy empty attributes, etc. If you go for server side deploy, you could think off server side pre-population

Comment: To answer your question in shot; no. You have to do this programatically, because there is no other way of ensuring the value otherwise. How come you are asking for the value twice? If you already have the E-mail, why ask for it again? If it's because you somehow need to transfer the value from one page to another in order to retain the value for later use, you can `POST` it to the other page, or use `GET`. Whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user has autofill set-up and the form is correctly built using best practices then the user can focus the input and have a selection of email addresses available.

If you want to use a value previously used on your site/the users’ session, then programmatically would be the way to go.

This article is quite helpful in helping you follow form best practices.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/input/forms